# How can we check the reply mode? In Outlook Add-in using Javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

How can we check the reply mode? In Outlook Add-in using Javascript.

using this I can only check Read or Compose mode

```
if (Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyForm != undefined) {

       // read mode

       console.log("read mode");

       }

   } else {
       // compose mode

       console.log("compose Mode")

       }

   }
```

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT  any way to check reply mode in Outlook